# Unity: Why do my 2 gameObjects 'share' materials?

Tags: unity, textures

no one has answered this on Unity answers yet so I thought I might as well ask this here:

recently, I imported my .blend game character and the character consisted of 2 colors: Red and black. Therefore as unity always does it creates 2 red and black materials for the colors of the character. Then, I imported the grass platform for my game. Because the grass platform is green and brown, Unity should have created 2 new green and brown materials and the platform should have stayed green and brown. But, instead, my grass platform decided to use my character's materials and my platform is now red and black. (If I import the grass platform first, my character becomes brown and green). Please help, this is an extremely annoying problem, thanks!

Comment: Are the materials called the same i blender? You need to make sure you have unique names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure they are named differently in blender, also make sure that you try importing to different folders in unity. If that fails, just re-apply the materials? (Create the new ones yourself)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I made sure to rename my materials differently and it worked! Thank you Daniel Holst and GMR516 for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this myself, but with U/V scaling of a material on 2 different objects.  I guess the only way to solve this is to duplicate the material and assign a different one to each object and then adjust the material to suit the object.